# Insert data in a datagrid view base on column header value C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have added a column header to my datagridview from a list in excel. Now I have a dictionary with the key as the column header and value needs to be inserted to the new row. One dictionary per row.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_ExitPoints.Rows)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dgv_ExitPoints.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
         String header = dgv_ExitPoints.Columns[j].HeaderText;
          if(exitPointDictionary.ContainsKey(header)
          {
              ???
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you know the key exists, you can access the value via `exitPointDictionary[header]` and add it to the row.

Comment: There's technically not a question here.

Comment: Thanks but how do I insert the row? and is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You could add the data to a DataTable and set it as the DataSource of the DataGridView..

Comment: Thanks can you send me a link to what you are reffering too?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. If anyone is interested in future:

```
`for (int j = 0; j < dgv_ExitPoints.Columns.Count; j++)
 {
    String header = dgv_ExitPoints.Columns[j].HeaderText;
    if(exitPointDictionary.ContainsKey(header))
    {
         dgv_ExitPoints.Rows[counter].Cells[j].Value = exitPointDictionary[header].ToString();
     }
     ++counter;
 }`
```